# TypeScript: How to obtain return type of the instance of a generic function that has a specified parameter tuple type?

Tags: typescript, generics, return-type

Suppose I have generic function

```
function example<T>(a: T, b: number): SomeType<T> {
   // code goes here
}
```

But let's say for the sake of argument that I don't know whether `example` was generic on the type of the first or second parameter, or maybe it was generic with two type parameters. My goal is to determine the return type of the instantiation of `example` that takes argument tuple `[string, number]`. (So it would be nice to have something like `InstantiatedReturnType<F, ParamTuple>` so that in this case `InstantiatedReturnType<typeof example, [string, number]>` would be `SomeType<string>`.) I have verified that `typeof example` does extend the type `(...args: [string, number]) => any`, but I have not been able to find a way to extract the return type of the instantiation that has this parameter tuple type. In particular, if I take the intersection of the function types `typeof Example` and `(...args: [string, number]) => any` it has `ReturnType< >` equal to either `any` or `unknown` depending on the order I list the two types in the intersection. Also, because function types are contravariant in their parameters, I tried taking `ReturnType< >` of the union of these two types, but that didn't help either. Any suggestions or guidance would be welcome.

(My point about not knowing the structure of the template is I don't have the information to be able to say `ReturnType<typeof example<string>>` because maybe the instantiation that matches arguments `[string, number]` is actually `example<number>` because `example` was actually generic on the second parameter type, and explicit in the first parameter as a string. The use case is that I am given an object whose values are alternative functions I might want to call, some of which might be generic, and I am selecting the one to call based on matching the type of an argument tuple I have. That part works -- I can successfully extract the key (as a concrete type with just the one string inhabitant) whose value is a (possibly generic) function callable on the tuple type of the arguments I've got, but I also need to express the return type of what the call will produce, and I can't seem to manage that.)

UPDATE: A stripped down example of what I am trying to accomplish is in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYiEMC8MDeAoG2YCMCGATgFwwA8AKgDQB8AFPqdXqWAK4C2uApoQJQoaMfFSw4CAL1KVadAB5MqMAI6lohAJZgA5gORCohNt1E4VbNgpjzSuRABtu+MEoCeth07B6hAJgwAvhgYUK4ADtwwANLcrhAAsvhQwAAWWtoyMABqQqhoANpRMFowANaxIABmMBQAugC0APxMhbUw3HJQ3GAAJhDZMI3RMKzcAG68AfnlrlU1tQDcwaERMPGucGxgwCjWAHQHRNoQpPnq6UrsXLy1PsJgrsEA9E8wAMrcjsBQ6TBQKZEwoQQBFCGVYjBKiAwUdON0oP0zoYLjArjxCG0NP0AO7Q0rpDCOWAzUgxOKJZJpHRkFbcOYIEBKdabbYwXIwADkBEIHJgLxgAHkokpnD1OZJeQDCJEeiBuP1KvgNPYRf0evKNNKes9XgAhNiwFIgbF-JClMDGv4pJLwRB7bnCMJhewabhiqBIfAwJGaHSXTjotpQNjOyLS4OESDCGDnHSNELhSIs4AURO7Oi0+mIPj5TPVGZtABkaw2W2AwSJMDCIAgEA0uEcACVuBGwKRm63UxEyMmu9x2YZjNh+UKlNipU5+kawr8oWCAKKNxsCxukWkwAAGdhAjmcG+K-QtsHwtY02jA+AbkQ9fzTHNj2g5GH5AEFesV1fh7PZXNGIDuDQ0cAYFxNh7DFI8YAAfXVCJeigmBgP+SIOCSVJfhmPBuF+L1tG6XgNGAPYYHnPZtGIjRKmfV4fRRNEbgPGBpWdfBgDdPBf3ybddxcPBPGcTEwBgDhXEqMslGQoTsUiCAjTAsU8NgZDb1WDd6MIDdqMhaEqxrOsrw7NhI2IugKGtWBcUIUocQ0f4rSxVElQmR0gRAViUhFd9p24MTv1-UDwJjKB8H8vF0j2PggA). It shows selecting the proper key, and one unsuccessful attempt to obtain the return type of the "matching instantiation".

Comment: There is no pure type-level manipulation you can perform to get this; the language lacks true higher-kinded types so there's no way to express that.  There is [some support for higher order function inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) in the value level, but without a [mre] of your use case it's hard to know it it would work.  Could you provide one?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for taking a look; posted an example that I hope makes it clearer what I am trying to do.

Comment: I can't come up with any usable way to do this, sorry.  Without [higher kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) I don't think it's possible.  Would you like an answer that says "no, this can't be done" along with sources? Or are you looking for (terrible) workarounds involving doing stuff manually that the compiler can't do automatically?

Comment: Well, I surely wouldn't mind seeing the least terrible workaround if it's not too much trouble... But one feature I didn't put in the toy example is that the object might also have explicit functions as well, which conceivably could be the match. I'll update the example.

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/Nd2A0W) is the least terrible workaround I can think of, where you manually spell out the type logic from inputs to outputs.  Do you want that written up in the answer, or is it not of enough use to be worth my effort explaining it?

Comment: Oh, I get it, you just redundantly specify each return type as a transform of the parameter tuple type, for each of the candidates. Right, that is exactly what I was hoping to get the compiler to do for me based on the code. That's very helpful, no need to take the time to write out an answer. I really appreciate the time you took to make the example. I'll at least upvote your comments.

Comment: I will write out an answer but I won't digress into the workarounds (I told you they were terrible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is unfortunately not possible in TypeScript as of TS4.9.  There is no way to express operations on generics at the type level; there are no "generic generics" or *higher kinded types*, as requested in the longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).

So, while the compiler can figure out the output type of a generic function given a particular input *if you actually call the function* at the expression level (if `example("abc", 123)` appears in your code), and while there's even some [support for higher order generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) (e.g., you could get `call(example, "abc", 123)` to yield `string` if `call` has type `<A extends any[], R>(f: (...args: A)=>R, ...args: A)=>R`), there is no pure type-level equivalent.  At some point you have to actually call the functions with the actual inputs (or convince the compiler that you are doing so) to see what the output types will be.

There was a pull request at [microsoft/TypeScript#17961](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17961) which would have enabled type-level function application, so that, armed with, `type Example = typeof example` you could write `type RetType = Example(string, number)`.  But this was never merged into the language, and was essentially abandoned along with most of [microsoft/TypeScript#6606](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) a general request to be able to query types for all expressions without actually needing to emit these expressions to JavaScript.

There is currently an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179) for this feature.  It's listed as Awaiting More Feedback, meaning they need to hear more community engagement before even considering making it part of the language.  If it matters to you, you could give it a , and describe your use case and why it's compelling.  But I don't see any indication that it will happen anytime soon, even if it had more engagement.

This all means that the compiler can't do this for you, and you'll need to either give up completely, or refactor your code so that you are doing the type processing manually (and *maybe* you can get the compiler to *check* that you've done it correctly).  But such workarounds are not pleasant, and are not directly in scope for this question.

[Edit: corrected issue number above.]

Comment: And also as far as I can tell, the issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179 open as of this date is also a request for this identical feature.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's hard to keep track of these issues! 